# duplicate a proxy model in admin on django 1.8

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I want to have a model that appear two times on django-admin, on two differents apps, because admins have access to differents apps.

On stackoverflow, it is said this should work, but the answers are a few years old.

**And in my case, this doesn't work**

I'm workin on django 1.8

app1/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    thing = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    app = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

app1/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

app2/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from app1.models import Model

class CustomMyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CustomMyModelManager, self).get_queryset().filter(app='app2')

class CustomMyModel(MyModel):
    objects = CustomMyModelManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

app2/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomMyModel

admin.site.register(CustomMyModel)
```

How is this supposed to work on django 1.8 ?

Comment: btw, there might be typo, my code is way heavier than this, but this is the spirit. I checked my code like during 20 hours without seeing any typo, and it still doesn't work. **is it supposed to work on django 1.8 ?**